# Run an anonymous block on a specific background thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

At first glance it seemed like an easy question, but I just can't figure how to run an anonymous block on a certain background thread i.e. I am looking for the blocks equivalent of `-performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.

Related: Is it possible to associate a dispatch queue with a certain background thread, just like the main queue is associated with the application's main thread?

*Edit* Clarified that I am looking to run an anonymous block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw this function `RunOnThread()` recently in Mike Ash's [PLBlocksPlayground](http://mikeash.com/tmp/PLBlocksPlayground.zip) (zip file, see BlocksAdditions.m):

```
void RunOnThread(NSThread *thread, BOOL wait, BasicBlock block)
{
    [[[block copy] autorelease] performSelector: @selector(my_callBlock) onThread: thread withObject: nil waitUntilDone: wait];
}
```

This is what I was looking for.

There are a bunch of other very useful blocks related utilities in PLBlocksPlayground, most of which Mr. Ash explains in this [post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html).

Comment: Link appears to be broken, anyone know where the content is?

Comment: No idea where the content is now. I have asked Mike Ash (the author of PLBlocksPlayground) about this though; hopefully we will know its new location soon.

Comment: I have updated the link -- it now points to a zip file which you can download.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you right you should do this:

```
dispatch_queue_t thread = dispatch_queue_create("your dispatch name", NULL);
dispatch_async(analyze, ^{
    //code of your anonymous block
});
dispatch_release(thread);
```

You also can write some method, which will take block to it, but you should know what type of parameters will it holds:

```
-(void)performBlock:(void (^)(SomeType par1, SomeType par2))block ToData:(Sometype)data;
```

You can call it with anonymous block:

```
[something performBlock:^(SomeType par1, SomeType par2){
  //do your stuff
} ToData: data]
```

And in method you can call your block as a simple C function:

```
block(par1, par2);
```

Comment: I don't think GCD gives any guarantees regarding which thread a dispatch queue runs on; so I don't think your first solution will work. Your second solution is more interesting; I think it should work -- will try it out and update.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGupta is correct. A dispatch_queue is not the same as a thread. A dispatch_queue can run on any number of threads.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, the accepted one below is correct

Answer (score -1):

A block is a function.  Call it like you would call any other function.

Comment: I should mention that I was looking to run an anonymous block on a background thread.